# TypeConverter/InstanceDescriptor failing when ASP.NET project with my user control is compiled/run

Tags: c#

I am having problem with TypeConverter/InstanceDescriptor.

I have a class called MyClass

```
public class MyClass
{
    private ICollection<Color> _colors;
    public MyClass(ICollection<Color> colors)
    {
        _colors = colors;
    }

    public MyClass(string colors)
    {
        if("MyColors".equals(colors))
        {
        .
        .
        .
        }
    }

    .
    .
    .
}
```

MyUserControl has property MyProperty of type MyClass.

Now, when i drag and drop this property, and change its value so that xml code is generated.
Now, i compile and end up with this error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

```
public static ColorGenerator FromString(object value)
{
    TypeConverter tc = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(MyClass));
    if (tc.CanConvertFrom(typeof(string)))
        return tc.ConvertFrom(null, null, value) as MyClass;
    else return null;
}
.
.
.
if(destinationType == typeof(InstanceDescriptor))
{
    MethodInfo mi = typeof(MyTypeConverter).GetMethod("FromString", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static, null, new Type[] { typeof(string) }, null);
     return new InstanceDescriptor(mi, new object[] { "MyColors" }, true);
}
.
.
.
```

If my logic is as follows, then i end up with "Unable to generate code for a value of type 'MyNamespace.MyClass'. This error occurred while trying to generate the property value for MyClass." error when compiled.

```
.
.
.
if(destinationType == typeof(InstanceDescriptor))
{
            ConstructorInfo ci = typeof(MyClass).GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(string) });
            InstanceDescriptor descriptor = new InstanceDescriptor(ci, new object[] { "LightColors" });
            return descriptor;
}
.
.
.
```

Can anyone please explain to me what these errors mean, and why they are happening?

Thanks a million in advance,
Anony.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by,
1. Used TypeConverterAttribute on MyClass
2. Created a static property on MyClass that returns me an static readonly instance of MyClass
3. In the ConvertTo() method, I created the InstanceDescriptor that takes a PropertyInfo corresponding to the new static property of MyClass.

... :)

Things went well.

-Anony